# selenium get element by css selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get user details from each block as given

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/public/karim-pathan")         
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
li_link = []
for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('clearfix'):
    print s
    print s.find_element_by_css_selector('_8o._8r.lfloat._ohe').get_attribute('href')
    print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
```

it says:

> unable to find element with css selector

any hint appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a mere guess based on assumption that you are not logged in. You are getting exception cause for all class clearfix, element with `._8o._8r.lfloat._ohe` does not exists. So your code isn't reaching the required elements. Anyhow, if you are trying to fetch href and img source of results, you need not iterate over all clearfix cause as suggested by `@leo.fcx`, your css is incorrect, trying the css provided by leo, you can achieve the desired result as:

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/public/karim-pathan")         
for s in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._8o._8r.lfloat._ohe'): // there didn't seemed to iterate over each class of clearfix
    print s.get_attribute('href')
    print s.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
```

P.S. sorry for any syntax, never explored python binding :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using all class-names that the element applies, adding a `.` to the beginning of your CSS selector should fix it.

Try this:

```
s.find_element_by_css_selector('._8o._8r.lfloat._ohe')
```

instead of:

```
s.find_element_by_css_selector('_8o._8r.lfloat._ohe')
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @leo.fcx pointed about the selector, [*wait for search results to become visible*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "all_search_results")))
```

Comment: added it, still no change

Comment: @nlper okay, could you try locating the links inside every search result by tag name? `s.find_element_by_tag_name("a")`.

Comment: no, it gives `Unable to find element with tag name 'a'` @alecxe

Comment: @nlper okay, thanks, which browser are you using? Also, do you have a "login to facebook" step?